# Implementing Live Agent chat in salesforce

Tags: community, chat

I want to know that what all the additional functionalities I can add-on with implementing the live agent chat. For Ex: I can implement multi-lingual support. Similarly, what other functionalities I can implement and how?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of [5 additional functionalities](https://blogs.perficient.com/salesforce/2014/01/02/5-salesforce-live-agent-chat-enhancements-you-need-to-know-about/) available with Live Agent. For implementation you have to search individually.

- Multi-Lingual Support
- Chat Transfer
- Supervisor Controls Including Agent Whispering
- Proactive Chat Invites
- Tab Warning